# How to get javascript object property using part of name

Tags: javascript

I have property `yaCounter27352058` in window object.
I can easily get it using bracket notation

```
window["yaCounter27352058"]
```

The problem is that I don't know object id, so in general I want to get all objects like this

```
window["yaCounter*"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query based of Object.keys:

```
var values = Object.keys(window).filter(function(el) {
    return /^yaCounter.*?/i.test(el);
});
```

Then you can iterate:

```
values.forEach(function(key) {
   console.log(key, window[key]); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact you can't.
But you can do something else.

You can try to list all your properties with

`var properties = Object.keys(window)`.

Then with a regexp you will select your properties starting with yaCounter :

```
var reg = new RegExp("^yaCounter.*");
var goodProp = [];
properties.forEach(function(prop) {
    if (reg.exec(prop) != null)
        goodProp.push(prop);
}
```

And them use these with :

```
goodProp.forEach(function(val) {
    window[val];
}));
```

Comment: `exec` only takes a string, so this would only match if the `yaCounter` variable was the first property on `window` which it's unlikely to be...

Comment: Yes you are right, exec should be called for each item of the properties array.